# How to count the number of questions that have the average score below 3.0 in Power BI

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

Here is a question. How to count the number of questions that have the average score below 3.0. I have created the measure for the scores which is the answer column for these questions as shown in the table below with values but not sure how to count the number of questions that have the average score or answers below 3.0. In this case below there are two questions Q4 and Q5 with average score below 3.0. Here is an example. How can you write a DAX to solve this?

[image]

Comment: What about countif() ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to use COUNTIF. Do you have some examples for this scneraio?

Comment: Excel has a help entry and there are examples on here.

Comment: The first step is to unpivot the data in PQ then you can write a DAX expression

Comment: Here is the table example. The decimal values are the averages. On the left are the course titles in one column. Across the matrix are the questions as string. The values are the averages which I'm trying to check which question has the value below 3.0 and count the number of questions which has the average value below 3.0 and show in one column. In the screen shot below the question 2 for course 3 has average below 3.0 and also for course 2 the question 4 has value below 3.0 and I would like to count those questions and display in one column. Any ideas?